# What is at 298 K at standard entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

> The standard entropy of a substance is the entropy of $1$ mol at $298$K and $1$ bar pressure.

What exactly *is* at $298$K? The system or the surrounding?

Let's take vapour as an example where $ \ \ce{H2O(g)} \ \ \ \ S^{\Phi}_{298}\approx188.8  \ JK^{-1}mol^{-1}$. Is the $298$K referring to the temperature of the gaseous $\ce{H2O}$? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

298K refers to the temperature of the substance and its surroundings. 298K is about 25 degrees Celsius. In other words, the statement can be simplified as:

> The standard entropy of a substance is the entropy of 1 mol at room temperature and pressure.

Comment: the part that's confusing me is if the substance $H_{2}O$ is also at $25ºC$ then how can we say it is a gas  and find its entropy?

Comment: As you mention, vapor, is water in the gas phase at temperatures lower than 100 oC. That's like humidity.

Answer (score 0):

298 K and 1 atm is a hypothetical state for pure water vapor, based on treating the water vapor as an ideal gas.  You take the entropy of water vapor at 100 C and 1 atm., and then use the ideal gas heat capacity at constant pressure to then get the entropy at the hypothetical state of 298 and 1 atm using $dS=C_pdT/T$.

If you know the entropy of formation of liquid water at 25 C and 1 atm, another way of getting the entropy of formation of water vapor in the hypothetical ideal gas state would be to determine the entropy change for the following path:  drop the pressure on the liquid water to the equilibrium vapor pressure at 25C, vaporize the liquid water to water vapor at 25 C, compress the water vapor using the ideal gas relationship for compression of an ideal gas, to 1 atm.